# AWSMarketplaceMeteringClientBuilder.withRegion() is not visible

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am using AWS SDK for Java to use in AWS Metering service. When I tried to use `AWSMarketplaceMeteringClientBuilder` to create a `AWSMarketplaceMeteringClient`, I found that if I use `withRegion(Region region)` method, I get following compile time error:

```
The method withRegion(Region) from the type AwsClientBuilder<AWSMarketplaceMeteringClientBuilder,AWSMarketplaceMetering> is not visible
```

The client code is as shown below:

```
AWSMarketplaceMeteringClient metClient = (AWSMarketplaceMeteringClient) AWSMarketplaceMeteringClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.getCurrentRegion())
        .withCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance())
        .build();
```

And when I try to use the `setRegion(Region region)` method of `AWSMarketplaceMeteringClient` directly, I get following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Client is immutable when created with the builder.
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.checkMutability(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:854)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.setRegion(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:349)
```

So how should I use the withRegion(Region region) method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we observe closely, AwsClientBuilder class has following methods:

```
public final Subclass withRegion(Regions region) { }
public final Subclass withRegion(String region) { }
private Subclass withRegion(Region region) { }
```

I was trying to use method withRegion(Region region), which is private in this base class. So we should use method withRegion(Regions region) [NOTE: The parameter is Regions instead of Region]. Using this method solved my issue.